# To learn and use Oracle as a student - is it better to download a local windows 10 copy or use the online free tier

Tags: python, windows, oracle, jupyter-notebook

Starting a new information database class - wanted to get a few thoughts and feedback from the group as to is it better to download a local Oracle 19C / 12 C Windows copy or sign up and use the on-line free tier.  Oracle is required.

Expecting to be using this application for the next year or so as I complete my masters.

Some factors looking for feedback:
1) Easy to set up - to where the first table is made
2) Limitation on a local copy (online is clear and somewhat limited)
3) Manitaince expectation for a local copy
4) How much does a local copy open my laptop to more cyber risks
5) Primary interface will be Python - mostly likely with notebooks
6) Other points worthy to note and consider as seen fit to add

Reference :
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html
https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/?source=:ow:o:h:po:Search&intcmp=:ow:o:h:po:Search

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily option based but, if you are not intending to study/practice 'DBA' related tasks (backup, recovery, replication etc) and have a capable internet connection (ie no need to work without internet) then you probably won't benefit from a full local install.

If you do want that local version, look for the Database Virtualbox image rather than installing on Windows. If the windows install 'breaks', it tends to leave a mess that makes an install almost impossible to achieve. In a regular enterprise environment, the database would tend to sit on its own server and any install issue would be resolved by reinstalling windows and starting again.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html

Comment: Gray - thank you - the maintenance / install potential issues alone are enough for me to follow your suggestion and go with the on-line free tier to start and buy up as needed over the next year. I have upvoted your answer...

Comment: @Joe, you haven't upvoted (nor accepted) *anything*. Just saying :)

Comment: I second the use of a VirtualBox image to run the DB.  And then if you want to connect Python from your Windows tools, you can do some VirtualBox port mapping like https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/the-easiest-way-to-install-oracle-database-on-apple-mac-os-x You would install cx_Oracle and Instant Client natively on your Windows machine.

Comment: Christopher, Thank you I will hook it up once I am able to get Oracle cloud working. Currently, run to sign up issues. and the chat team is understandably a little slow.

Comment: Littlefoot, I added a comment thanking Gray for the great advice yesterday.  I do appreciate everyone looking out and ensuring the social norms are followed.  Stack is a great tool.  Currently, I can not upvote - rep point too low.